# how to count total student according to 'course' model in django

Tags: django

I am trying to count the number of the student according to CourseMasterModel.
I did it in MySQL, but I want to in Django.

> select cn.course_name,count(st.id) from course_master
>   cn,semister_master sem,division_master di,student_profile st where
>   st.division_id = di.id and di.semister_id = sem.id and sem.course_id =
>   cn.id GROUP BY cn.course_name;

---

```
class CourseMasterModel(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    total_semister = mod`enter code here`els.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "course_master"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Course (Department)'
        verbose_name = "Course"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name


class SemisterMasterModel(models.Model):
    semister = models.SmallIntegerField()
    total_div = models.SmallIntegerField()
    course = models.ForeignKey(CourseMasterModel,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Semister_master"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Semister'
        verbose_name = "semister"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s  -   %d" %(self.course.course_name,self.semister)

class DevisionMasterModel(models.Model):
    div_name = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    semister = models.ForeignKey(SemisterMasterModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "division_master"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Division'
        verbose_name = "Division"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s - %s"%(self.semister.course.course_name,self.semister.semister,self.div_name)

class StudentProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="profile")
    division = models.ForeignKey('core.DevisionMasterModel',on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Course / Semister / Division")
    roll_no = models.IntegerField()
    enrollment_no = models.IntegerField(unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This enrollment number has already been registered."})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Student_Profile"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate your `CourseMasterModel`, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

CourseMasterModel.objects.annotate(
    nstudents=Count('semistermastermodel__devisionmastermodel__studentprofilemodel')
)
```

The `CourseMasterModel`s that arise from this `QuerySet` have an extra attribute `.nstudents` that contains the number of related `StudentProfileModel`s.

> **Note**: usually the names of Django models have *no* `Model` suffix, so `CourseMaster` instead of <s>`CourseMasterModel`</s>.

In case you rename the models, the query is:

```
from django.db.models import Count

CourseMasterModel.objects.annotate(
    nstudents=Count('semistermaster__devisionmaster__studentprofile')
)
```